# Entering Bosnia, Croatia and Romania with a 2-entry Schengen visa

Tags: schengen-visas, romania, indonesian-citizens, entry-permit

I'm planning a trip with my girlfriend who has an Indonesian passport and a Double-Entry Schengen Visa issued by the republic of Austria.
We'd like to go from Austria via Hungary to Serbia and then via Bosnia to Croatia and back to Schengen (Slovenia).

Now there are some problems.

1. Going to Serbia is fine. Serbia lets Indonesians in with a stamp only.
2. But Bosnia probably not possible. Apparently we need a Mulit-Entry Schengen visa (called the embassy), they stated a double-entry is not enough. But I'm not willing to give up yet. Does anyone know if there is a chance to visit Bosnia? Visa is difficult as it's not possible to contact the consulate.
3. Croatia is slightly more complicated, but apparently we can get in as Croatia allows ([Source](http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/)):

> All third-country nationals who are holders of valid Schengen documents[...] do not require an additional (Croatian) visa for Croatia.
>
> Third-country nationals who are holders of:
>   uniform visa (C) for two or multiple entries, valid for all Schengen Area Member States;
>   [...]
>   do not require a visa for transit or intended stays in the territory of Croatia not exceeding 90 days in any 180-day period.

I'm just not sure if there is a difference if we enter from Serbia (having an invalid first visit already) or Slovenia (having it invalidated just at the Slovenian border).

4. Due to the problems with Bosnia the alternative route is to visit Timișoara in Romania instead of doing the tour in Bosnia and for Romania, which is like Croatia not part of Schengen I have even less information and at the embassy nobody ever picks up. I'm not sure if we are able to enter Romania from Serbia.

Has anyone of you ever had an experience like this and can advice me which part of the route is actually an option?

Comment: As a Romanian-born, I recommend you try and visit Bosnia instead if the visa problem works out. This time of the year there isn't much to see in Romania, only if you plan some trips to the mountains or some rural villages.

Comment: @TomasBy - when you enter Schengen area the first time your first stay gets validated. When you leave your first stay becomes invalid and you're in some kind of limbo between the two stays. Entering again validates your 2nd stay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one answered this and I only got a weird comment that Romania in winter is not nice I think I should post the route and the result:

My Indonesian gf had a double-entry Schengen visa and arrived in Austria. We went to Szeged first (no problem), then to Temeschburg (Romania) - they looked a little funny at her at the border, took finger-prints, but everything fine.

Then to Novi Sad (the Romanians were a little confused, they never had any Indonesian traveling by car there, but everything was fine).

Serbia was no problem at all.
Serbia to Croatia was fine too, no problem.

Croatia to Slovenia is only a problem if you cross at Hum Na Sutli, 7km away in Lupinjak it's ok. Hum Na Sutli only allows Schengen-Passport-Holders and Croatians to cross.